# efficient continuous data writes on HDD

Tags: c#, c, file-io, memory-mapped-files

In my application I need to continuously write data chunks (around 2MB) about every 50ms in a large file (around 2-7 GB). This is done in a sequential, circular way, so I write chunk after chunk into the file and when I'm at the end of the file I start again at the beginning.

Currently I'm doing it as follows:

In C# I call `File.OpenWrite` once to open the file with read access and set the size of the file with `SetLength`. When I need to write a chunk, I pass the safe file handle to the unmanaged `WriteFile` (kernel32.dll). Hereby I pass an overlapped structure to specify the position within the file where the chunk has to be written. The chunk I need to write is stored in unmanaged memory, so I have an `IntPtr` which I can pass to `WriteFile`.

Now I'd like to know if and how I can make this process more efficient. Any ideas?

Some questions in detail:

- Will changing from file I/O to memory-mapped file help?
- Can I include some optimizations for NTFS?
- Are there some useful parameters when creating the file that I'm missing? (maybe an unmanaged call with special parameters)

Comment: Is there a requirement that specifies writing data every n-milliseconds? You could buffer the data and write that every n-seconds. This reduces the access times (1000ms - 12ms = 998ms left to write at about 40MB/s) versus the non-buffered variant (50ms - 12ms = 38ms, 52MB/s).

Comment: As far as I know the file writes are already cached by the system. However, it might be interesting to inspect how a larger buffer like you suggested would perform compared to my current implementation. This especially since I have no control over how large the I/O cache is and how the caching is handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using better hardware will probably be the most cost efficient way to increase file writing efficiency.
There is a paper from Microsoft research that will answer most of your questions: [Sequential File Programming Patterns and Performance with .NET](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64538) and the [downloadable source code (C#)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/a6f86a1e-0278-4c72-9300-f747251c3bf0/) if you want to run the tests from the paper on your machine.

In short:

- The default behavior provides excellent performance on a single disk.
- Unbufffered IO should be tested if you have a disc array. Could improve write speed with a factor of eight.

This thread on [social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f816938e-363d-4e6a-8691-89a090bb485f/fast-file-write-with-overlapped-io) might also be of interest.